# VS Code Salesforce plugin deploy does not provide an error message

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

VS Code plugin for salesforce seems to be broken yesterday, It does not provide proper error message in case of failure.

Tried this in a developer org as well as scratch org. Neither deploy code or push gives an error message, and every time we need to go to Salesforce setup -> Deployment Status to view the details.

Is anyone aware of any workaround?

[image]

Comment: You have 1 problem on the PROBLEMS tab. Did you check that?

Comment: @sfdxfox unfortunately nothing there, added the screenshot. simply says `Push failed`.

Comment: Try `sfdx force:source:push -u username-or-alias -w 10 --loglevel trace --verbose`, you might get better output (use the terminal). Usually errors like this are from missing metadata in the repo, but without an error, might be difficult. The above command should give you more information.

Comment: seems push command does not have a `--verbose`, `ERROR running force:source:push:  Unexpected argument: --verbose` :(

Comment: Oh. Of all the commands that *should* have one... Well, maybe you can check your `USER_HOME_DIR/.sfdx` folder and see what the logs there say?

Comment: The logs in sfdx folder file on windows is quite big but does not provide a relevant error.

Comment: For what it's worth, the "workaround" I used was to open the org and view the errors under Deployment Status.

Comment: @CharlesT, did the same but apparently I was working on a dev org along with fellow developer. It was a bit of hassle, luckily the issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be working now, also noticed [this issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1411) is logged on github [`salesforcedx-vscode`](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode) project-

- [When I "deploy this source to org" and the deploy fails it no longer shows the errors in the panel](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1411).

---

For the fix to work, we need to update the sfdx CLI with `sfdx update` command, latest sfdx working version on my machine is `sfdx-cli/7.12.3`

Comment: The issue is *open*, updating sfdx won't do anything yet. I think maybe you mistook the linking of issue #871 at the bottom, which *is*closed, as inidcating that this new issue, #1411, is closed. Can you edit your answer?

Comment: Oh, yesh @ThomasTaylor you're right, but somehow it works now. This started working for me after updating sfdx CLI, also verified with my colleague. :) btw we are working on sandboxes; so using deploy command.

Comment: Solved my issue as well.  I went from 7.11.2-4a5bf6aa97 to 7.12.3-bfc421fa08.