# VS Code Deployment not showing detailed error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, deployment, vs-code

I'm using visual studio code to develop an aura component. Usually when i deploy a source to my org the error i was receiving was the same i can find in the "Deployment Status" Section on salesforce, but since yesterday the only error i'm getting is the following:

[image]

While the real error is the following:
[image]
I have already tried to uninstall and reinstall the extension but it still showing the same error.

I've also tried to run force:source:deploy with the Terminal in VSCODE with loglevel: trace and it's sill not showing anything detailed.
[image]

Does anyone know how to help? Thank you.

Comment: I have even got this error , if there is any issue with components items..The only solution to check where is it erroring out is to deploy break by break. Means remove the entire code and deploy blank template. Then add a block of code and deploy. You can see where excatly it is erroring out.

Comment: try to not specify --json and --loglevel. Did you specify default target org for deployment?

Comment: without specifing --json and --loglevel is showing the correct error but only if i deploy from the terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code Salesforce plugin deploy does not provide an error message](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266518/vs-code-salesforce-plugin-deploy-does-not-provide-an-error-message). This issue is resolved, you'd need to update your cli with 'sfdx update' command

Comment: Ok it worked, thank you.
I'll delete the post