# SFDX won't push to scratch org? No error detail

Tags: salesforcedx, error-messages, push

My current scratch org is expiring today, so I created a new scratch org and tried to push my source. It seems like it's working on the task for a minute or so, then gives me an error with no detail:

> ERROR running force:source:push:  Push failed.

I don't have a clue how to troubleshoot this. I'm pushing a substantial amount of code, custom objects, permissions, etc., so I'm used to having to tweak my .forceignore file to get things to push. But usually, there is detail in the error that tells me what needs to be adjusted.

I'll try using deploy on some things instead and see if that works.

Not sure if this is related to Summer '19, though my previous scratch org updated and things were working well there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code Salesforce plugin deploy does not provide an error message](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266518/vs-code-salesforce-plugin-deploy-does-not-provide-an-error-message)

Comment: Nope. -> sfdx update
sfdx-cli: Updating CLI... already on latest version: 7.12.3-bfc421fa08

Comment: I thought maybe it was caused by the version update, so I changed my sfdx-project.json to "sourceApiVersion": "46.0". Didn't work. Same error, no detail.

Comment: Oh that suck. try with and without the `--json` flag and see if it spits more details; from terminal `sfdx force:source:push -f`, I tried on my summer 19 scratch org and after updating the CLI, it seems to be working. Not sure what could be the issue :( Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the --json tip. That yield a list of all the errors I would have expected. Not happy to deal with a long list of errors, but at least I know what they are now!

Comment: I'm still working through my errors, and I still have to add --json every time I push. However, although it makes the error list longer (more vertical scrolling), I'm actually liking the JSON output on the errors. Easier to read since there's no wrapping. Also, the JSON output the error twice, once as "result[]" and again as "data[]". Makes it seem worse than it is... HEY, I was writing this as I was waiting for my latest push and it succeeded. Woo-hoo!

Answer (score 3):

Posting a follow up so we can close this issue.

After @Raul suggested adding `--json` to my push command, I was able to get the error detail I needed to adjust my push and get it to work. I don't think the push command was at fault, it was the return of error messages.

After my initial push, I was able to push in the normal way, though if there was a problem with the push, I didn't get the detail unless I added the `--json`. That was yesterday.

Today, just tried a push with an intentional error. Good news, it balked at the push and gave me the error message like normal. Well, almost normal:

> [Line: 16, Col: 1] LWC1503: Parsing error: Unexpected token (16:1) You know you can't fool me with that kind of blatant shenanigans!

Ok, I added that last bit.

Comment: Thanks for the post I ran into the same issue today and --JSON was the cure.  Just a couple of picklist values that were off.