# VS Code + sfdx: debug logs

Tags: salesforcedx, developer, debug, sfdx-plugin

Until a few weeks ago, vs code use to have a reasonable error message if there was an error when deploying.

But I notice the last few weeks this is change and it is not very descriptive the problem, eg:

[image]

**[image: strong text]**

Is there a way to display more information? I now finding myself copying and pasting my code into the dev console or the web browser to get the actual error message

Comment: Raul, not really sure in what world will be a possible duplicate, I am not saying there is an error, I am saying when the deployment fails due to an error in the code, a few weeks ago sfdx was showing exactly what line was the error, similar way when you do it in dev console, but now it just shows deployment fails

Comment: I had same issue and here is exact duplicate question: [VS Code Salesforce plugin deploy does not provide an error message](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266518/vs-code-salesforce-plugin-deploy-does-not-provide-an-error-message), the reason I did not mark this question as duplicate as current question has a detailed step to solve the issue.

Comment: fixed by updating sfdx (sfdx update), Raul: that links is different to the one on your first comment (the comment that you deleted it?), would have been nice if you started with that one, or at least dont delete your initial comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're hitting this bug:

https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1411

VS Code gets its error's from the cli and the cli has only been reporting errors on deploys when the --json flag is set.  My understanding is that a fix for this is currently under going QA and should be released soon.